# Com executable not instantiated

Tags: windows, com

I have an executable file (My.exe) that executes a dll.

The dll instantiates and execute 4 different com executables.

If the dll can't instantiate all 4 com executables it writes it to its log file and the run is terminated.

(The dll and the 4 com executables are closed products I get from an outer source).

On a server that has 32 cores I have a background service that polls a database, and executes My.exe on demand.

Until now I allowed maximum 10 instances of My.exe to run at the same now.

But now, I tried to increase the maximum to 30, and I found that some runs are terminated because one or other com executable could not be instantiated.

I did not have this problem before.

Although I've increased the maximum to 30, there were only 16 or 17 instances of My.exe trying to run at the same time, because that was the demand.

Can anyone help?

Comment: It sounds like another design would be more efficient e.g. having one My.exe running running at all times instead of starting a new process every time talk to the existing one. that way you can have the four dll's instantiated the whole time and do not have to worry if they get instantiated.

Comment: The way I do it which I described above is dictated from reasons that are not relevant here. I just want to understand what could be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

There is not enough information here to give you any kind of a real answer.  There are a myriad of things that could be wrong with the components, this could be to do with lack of resources, a race condition in the other objects, you need to contact the vendor or get the code.

Comment: I get the following error: Cannot create a file when that file already exists

Comment: Its probably because it is writing to a log file and the same file is being created by multiple instances.  I would imagine it is not designed to work with 30 instances.   You will need to contact the vendor